# Wordpress Multisite: Set template languages for a domain?

Tags: multisite

I have two domains set up in a Wordpress 3 Multisite blog. One of them is supposed to be in Swedish and the other in English. The template contains some texts that I want to translate for the different sites.

How do I set up different languages for the sites' frontend (using the language files in my template)?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Swedish language pack, and then you need to pick Swedish from that user's profile on that blog.

http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/localization/ The latter half of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some default plugins like "[Global Translator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/global-translator/)" or "Google translator" for your wordpress.

Hope this help...

Comment: Sorry, it was not what I was looking for. The content will be completely different between the two sites. But they will use the same template. And that template contains <?php _e("A text") ?> and language files for Swedish and English. For mydomain1.com I want it to use the Swedish language file and for mydomain2.com I want it to use the English language file.

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct WordPress core language packs (the mo files, basically).

In a multisite installation, this will enable a selection on the Settings->General page which lets you select the language for that individual site. This setting will then affect the language choice for both front and back ends of the site, including letting it use the relevant language files for the theme.